# autoplay bug while building tkinter flash card app

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

The function p in the code should be displaying english word and its sanskrit translation after few seconds as the play_b is clicked but it seems to skip every word and only display last word please help!
here is the code

```
import pandas
from customtkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

eng_count = 0

#play all words in order
def p():
    global eng_count, data_dict
    while eng_count < len(data_dict)-1:
        window.after(500, func=start)
        window.after(3000, func=flip)
        eng_count += 1

#goto next word
def r():
    global eng_count, slides_label
    canvas.itemconfig(qna, text="Q")
    eng_count += 1
    slides_label.configure(text=f"{eng_count}/{len(data_dict)}")
    start()

#goto prev word
def l():
    global eng_count, slides_label
    if eng_count <= 0:
        eng_count = 0
    else:
        canvas.itemconfig(qna, text='Q')
        eng_count -= 1
        slides_label.configure(text=f"{eng_count}/{len(data_dict)}")
        start()

#Disp word in eng.
def start():
    global eng_count
    canvas.itemconfig(information, text='')
    canvas.itemconfig(title, text=data_dict[eng_count]['English'])

#flip the card
def flip():
    global eng_count
    canvas.itemconfig(qna, text='A')
    canvas.itemconfig(title, text='')
    canvas.itemconfig(information, text=data_dict[eng_count]['Sanskrit'])


data = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')
data_dict = data.to_dict(orient='records')
print(data_dict)

window = Tk()
window.title('Flash card')

img = Image.open('images/card.png')
card = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

img = Image.open('images/left.png')
left_button = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

img = Image.open('images/right.png')
right_button = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

img = Image.open('images/shuffle.png')
shuffle = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

img = Image.open('images/play.png')
play = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

canvas = CTkCanvas(width=700, height=450, highlightthickness=0)

canvas.create_image(350, 200, image=card)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=7)
title = canvas.create_text(350, 120, text='', font=('THE BOLD FONT', 20, 'bold'))
information = canvas.create_text(350, 190, text='', font=('THE BOLD FONT', 20, 'bold'))

play_b = CTkButton(window, image=play, text='', width=5,command=p)
play_b.grid(row=1, column=0)

shuffle_b = CTkButton(window, image=shuffle, text='', width=5)
shuffle_b.grid(row=1, column=1)

left_b = CTkButton(window, image=left_button, text='', width=5, command=l)
left_b.grid(row=1, column=4)

slides_label = CTkLabel(window, text=f"{eng_count}/{len(data_dict)}", width=1, text_color='black')
slides_label.grid(row=1, column=5)

right_b = CTkButton(window, image=right_button, text='', width=5, command=r)
right_b.grid(row=1, column=6)

flip_b = CTkButton(window, text='Flip It', width=5, font=('THE BOLD FONT', 20, 'bold'), command=flip)
flip_b.place(x=315, y=355)

qna = canvas.create_text(50, 40, text="Q", font=('THE BOLD FONT', 15, 'bold'))

start()
window.mainloop()
```

this is the data used as csv file:

```
English,Sanskrit
I (1sg),अहम् (ahám)
you (2sg),त्वम् (tvám)
"he, she, it (3sg)",स (sá)
we (1pl),"वयम् (vayám), नस् (nas)"
you (2pl),"यूयम् (yūyám), वस् (vas)"
they (3pl),ते (té)
this,इदम् (idám)
that,तत् (tát)
here,"अत्र (átra), इह (íha)"
there,तत्र (tátra)
who,क (ká)
what,किम् (kím)
where,"कुत्र (kútra), कुह (kúha), क्व (kvà)"
when,कदा (kadā́)
how,कथम् (kathám)
not,न (ná)
all,"सर्व (sárva), विश्व (víśva)"
many,बहु (bahú)
some,किञ्चिद् (kiñcid)
```

First i used time.sleep but it kept crashing but now when i use this its skipping all words

Comment: The delay specified by the first parameter to `.after()` is relative to *the current moment in time*, not the end of the previous `.after()` as you seem to expect.  So, with N items in the dictionary, you schedule N calls to `start()`, *all* of which will fire in half a second, and N calls to 'flip()`, all of which will fire in 3 seconds.